Server side api can't pass cookies in NextJS app router
In my nextjs app, I am trying to fetch data by using async await mechanism like this
export const getHomeData = async (tokenCalled4PublicApis: string) => {
    try {
        // const all = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN', { cookies });
        // console.log('all cookies', all);
        const data = await fetch(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/${API_ENDPOINTS.HOME}`,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenCalled4PublicApis}`,
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    // abc: all,
                    'Cache-Control':
                        'public, max-age=60, stale-while-revalidate=60'
                },
                credentials: 'include'
            }
        );
        const result = await data.json();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching platform token:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

Unfortunately not getting data, as in this way i won't be able to pass cookies set by API. How to pass browser cookies in server-side fetch functions?

There's the cookies function that allows you to read incoming request cookies from server-side, you can read about it here

I believe you can do this. You can read the docs from HERE too.
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
 
export default function Page() {
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const all = cookieStore.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    ...  ...  ...

You can access cookies from the actual page, and you can use it wherever you want to. You may also pass it to your function like this: getHomeData(all)
Hope it helps! :)

This is how I solve this after doing many research and over coming trials and errors.
export const getBookInfo = async (bookCode: string) => {
    const cookieList = cookies().getAll();
    let pushedData: string[] = [];
    cookieList.forEach((cookie) => {
        if (cookie.name === 'XSRF-TOKEN') {
            const val = `XSRF-TOKEN=${encodeURIComponent(cookie.value)}`;
            pushedData.push(val);
        }
        if (cookie.name === 'laravel_session') {
            const val = `laravel_session=${encodeURIComponent(cookie.value)}`;
            pushedData.push(val);
        }
    });
    const result = pushedData.join(';');
    const arrayResult = result.toString();
    

//I make the cookies as per my requirements.
    
    try {
        const tokenCalled4PublicApis = await getPlatformToken();
        const data = await fetch(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/${API_ENDPOINTS.book_info}?book_code=${bookCode}`,
            {
                credentials: 'include',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenCalled4PublicApis}`,
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    Referer: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}`,
                    Cookie: arrayResult //passed it here
                }
            }
        );
        const result = await data.json();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching platform token:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

In this way, we can easily pass cookies to the backend server, if not other ways work like credentials: true etc.
